# Change sound in expo.sendPushNotificationsAsync

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to play some other sound when hitting any notification in my expo app from node server.I can't find any other sound than 'default'.Is there any other option I can use to play some other sound other than the default one on notifications in expo.My nodeJS code is below:

```
const receipts = expo.sendPushNotificationsAsync([
            {
              to: userObj.pushToken,
              sound: 'default',
              body: notification,
              data: { withSome: notification },
              priority: 'high',
            },
          ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I looked up in the Message Format section of the [docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/push-notifications) and found this :

> A sound to play when the recipient receives this notification. Specify
>       "default" to play the device's default notification sound, or omit this
>       field to play no sound.
>
> ```
> Note that on apps that target Android 8.0+ (if using `expo build`, built
> in June 2018 or later), this setting will have no effect on Android.
> Instead, use `channelId` and a channel with the desired setting.
> ```
>
> **sound?: 'default' | null,**

Looks like it is not possible to change sound through app.